# Scrapy doesn't find/respond to URL

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape a couple of pages starting from [this URL.](http://example.com//!ut/p/b1/hctNDoIwGEXRtbiC9hNbyrAYi0BBSVF-JqQxaiooUYQoqxcXYHyzm5yHSlQAodRiAPYc5ai86cGc9dO0N918u6TVFoKEucDxxnME9tNwK-JQesQhEygmgH-M43__YgL2T0AoSlGOF5W64Iccl00gc79TtbW7OGrNAL8NhKka5cgIF1UxqFUVvc0rdhfG27u6Tvqj3LUPGZE4UZ2_zE53Kg6aiF5HhrtQZ14yQ_G6vR7RtWwYMD77AL82GHE!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/)

But the spider doesn't follow any links and when I try the link in the shell I get the following message: `no event found.` And the shell does not open up.

Should I maybe escape some nasty signs in the url?

All help much appreciated!

Comment: `no event found` doesn't explain anything; is like `it's raining outside`. Can you add more information :D

Comment: @nramirezuy it's true, that message is a bit cryptic -- bash really could show a friendlier message. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the URL you're using has an exclamation mark `!` on it -- the message you see is not related to Scrapy -- it's a message from the shell (`bash`, the interpreter of the command line).

It happens with any command in the interactive shell if you use the `!`, see:

```
$ scrapy shell http://example.com/#!something
-bash: !something: event not found
$ echo http://example.com/#!something
-bash: !something: event not found
```

Wrap the URL around quotes and it should work:

```
$ echo 'http://example.com/#!something'
http://example.com/#!something
$ scrapy shell 'http://example.com/#!something'
2014-12-18 22:25:33-0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
```

#### Related:

https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found